# TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined with firebase reauthenticateWithCredential

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Not exactly sure what I am doing wrong here, I have looked at other forum post and this is what they say to do to re-auth a user. But I am getting an error of:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined` on this line here:

`const credentials = fire.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, user.currentPass);`

Here is the code:

```
 const currentUser = fire.auth().currentUser;
 const credentials = fire.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, user.currentPass);
 currentUser
  .reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials)
  .then(() => {
    alert('Success');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    alert(err);
  });
```

Comment: How are you defining `fire` here?

Comment: `const fire = firebase.initializeApp(config);`, Everything else is working for the fire part, like the currentUser works just fine etc...

Comment: That explains it. Update the above to: `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(...)`.

Comment: That doesnt work , fire references the firebase it is the same thing

Comment: You have to hook up your firebase to your config so just using firbase alone would not work here @bojeil

Comment: It is not the same thing. If you are doing: `const firebase = require('firebase');` you should use `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider`. This is defined under the firebase namespace. It is not an instance method.

Comment: That did not work either I will have to create another project and test from scratch

Comment: head over to [this place](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) if you are using admin

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Rai checkout my answer

Answer (score 4):

Like @bojeil answered, it's a namespace so, for instance and if you're using typescript and you used `firebase.initializeApp(config);` in another class, just add again the import in the class where you user the credential method with `import * as Firebase from 'firebase/app';`

As u can see in the doc `credential` it's a static method in a static class that's why you need the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You've imported firebase in the wrong way. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider#.credential) is what it says in the document.
[Official Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymcZI.png)

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
const cred = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
    email,
    password
);
```

Comment: My fire is firebase i just didnt show that i named it like so doing `import fire from 'firebase'`

Comment: I think the problem is with this import. Because the export name in firebase module was not named fire. If you want that name, you can import firebase first and then assign it to variable fire.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and none of these answers helped me.

This worked for me:

```
const cred = fire.firebase_.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
```

I'm not entirely sure why, but I just tried all the options available on `fire` in the dev tools until I came across firebase_ which had the option of `EmailAuthProvider`.  Maybe someone else here knows why.